# jmeter : how to save parameter from response to external file and use it to enter another page?

Tags: jmeter

How can i Save parameter or any word from the response of the page to external file (txt ot csv)ang get this parameter from the file to enter another page ? 
In fact I want to be able to change the parameter dynamically via file.
Thanks.

Comment: your question is very confusing. Please provide more steps on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

**To save the whole response thing into a file:**

1. Add a [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) as a child of the sampler, whose data you need to save.
2. Add the following code to the PostProcessor's "Script" area

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

   File file = new File("/path/to/your/file.txt");
   FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, data);
   ```

**To read file contents in JMeter:**

Just use [__FileToString](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) function wherever file's content is required as:

```
${__FileToString(/path/to/your/file.txt,,)}
```

For more information on Beanshell bit refer to [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell).

For high loads it will be better to replace Beanshell PostProcessor with [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and choose "groovy" as the language (you'll need groovy-all.jar somewhere in JMeter's classpath)